# Can't get motor hat to run motor on windows iot

Tags: c#, raspberry-pi, windowsiot, adafruit

I have a raspberry pi which and a motor hat.

I am trying to get an adafruit motor hat to drive a motor but no power is going to the wires connecting the motor.

I have the following code

```
    public MainPage()
    {
       mHat= new MotorHat();
       motor1 = mHat.GetMotor(3);
       motor1.SetSpeed(255);
       motor1.Run(DCMotor.Command.FORWARD);
     }
```

the code runs without error, I have 4 AA batteries powering the motor hat.

there appears to be just over 3v going to the SDA pin if I connect a multi-meter to it and gnd.

Is the motor hat faulty or am I doing something wrong?

------------Update----------
I have checked the voltage before and after the small controller chips that sit just before the motor connections. There is around 3v on the one side and nothing the side of the motors which suggests that the board is likely to be fine but that the board is not being told to run the motor?

Is the code correct above?

Comment: How much voltage do you expect on SDA pin?

Comment: Not sure... I would probably expect around the 3v mark as it is coming from the pi.

Comment: I have not motor hat attached and test the voltage of the SDA pin, is 3.33V.

Comment: The voltage of the SDA pin is not the issue. I was simply confirming that it appears to be working and so passing information to the hat. The problem is the motor pins are not showing any voltage and hence the motor does not turn.

Comment: If you connect the motor pin to the hat you need check the hat output is valid or not. If you connect to the pi you need check the pin mode is output or not.

Comment: How do I check if the hat output is valid?

Comment: What's implementation of the MotorHat class? Do you use any library?

Comment: That adafruit iot library. However I have just found a sample project from them and it does not run the motor either.... I suspect the board is not working.